# Pip installed package can't find conda packages

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I have the following problem:
I installed conda and everythings fine, but I need mdfreader
as well which is not part of the conda installation.

Installing mdfreader will install packages that have already been
installed by conda.

[image: duplicate packages]

Is this the way it is supposed to be? Uninstalling the duplicate
pip packages will stop the module from working.

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

I'd like to avoid having duplicate packages.
Is that possible?

Comment: Weird, what happens if you use pip to remove that one?

Comment: In an interactive python session I can import lxml, but I can't import mdfreader which needs the pip installed lxml version and causes the exception.

Comment: Does is break if you remove the conda one?

Comment: I guess not. I always tried to keep the conda packages, but maybe it's better the other way around.